# Проверка бд на контакт в C#

Tags: c#, .net, ado

Как проверить в catch контакт на наличие одного и того же телефона:
Если добавляемый номер телефона существует, то выдать ошибку.

```
 public bool Insert (contactClass c)
    {
        bool isSuccess = false;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myconnstrng);
        try
        {
            string sql = "INSERT INTO [TContactPersons] ([Ім`я], [Прізвище], [Телефон], [Адреса], [Група]) VALUES(N'" + c.FirstName+ "', N'" + c.LastName + "', N'" + c.PhoneNumber + "', N'" + c.Address.Trim() + "', N'" + c.Other + "')";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            conn.Open();
            int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (rows>0)
            {
                isSuccess = true;
            }
            else
            {
                isSuccess = false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
        return isSuccess;
    }
```

Comment: *Вы же в курсе что такое SQL-инъекция и почему за такой код как у вас убивают на месте?*

Answer (score 2):

Подобные вещи так не делаются. Вам придётся перехватывать код ошибки, парсить. Код будет хрупким (зависеть от кода внешних библиотек майкрософт, которые могут неожиданно поменяться), будет сложно проверять правильность сразу нескольких полей (не только телефон, но и, допустим, емейл)

Правильно делать это следующим образом. Проверки должны выполняться ПЕРЕД вставкой в базу. Кроме того, можно сразу сделать уникальный индекс в базе по полям, куда нельзя вставлять дубликаты.